# Parse push notification in Swift 2 iOS 9

Tags: swift, parse-platform, apple-push-notifications, swift2, ios9

I'm trying to display Push Notifications in my first app using the Parse.com website and I have followed the tutorial and other website guidelines and when everything seems to be fine, the notification is not appearing in my device.

Parse.com says that my certificate is fine and when I press the "Test Push notification" it says that everything is fine, but then the notification does not appear in my device.

It displays "0 push sent".

Here is my code (AppDelegate): I have to made some changes because I'm using the Swift 2 and there are some things wrong in the Parse guideline regarding the code.

Do you know why is not working? What I have to change to make it work?

```
import UIKit

import Parse

import Bolts

extension UIColor {
convenience init(hex: Int) {
    let r = hex / 0x10000
    let g = (hex - r*0x10000) / 0x100
    let b = hex - r*0x10000 - g*0x100
    self.init(red: CGFloat(r)/255, green: CGFloat(g)/255, blue: CGFloat(b)/255, alpha: 1)
}
}

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    // Registramos la Push Notification
    if application.applicationState != UIApplicationState.Background {

        let preBackgroundPush = !application.respondsToSelector("backgroundRefreshStatus")
        let oldPushHandlerOnly = !self.respondsToSelector("application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:")
        var pushPayload = false
        if let options = launchOptions {
            pushPayload = options[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] != nil
        }
        if (preBackgroundPush || oldPushHandlerOnly || pushPayload) {
            PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions)
        }
    }
    if application.respondsToSelector("registerUserNotificationSettings:") {
        let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    } else {
        //let types = UIRemoteNotificationType.Badge | UIRemoteNotificationType.Alert | UIRemoteNotificationType.Sound
        //application.registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(types)
    }

    Parse.setApplicationId("ynwxRlK1AYrB3ib36ELpyDbWEedg9LTWarTSFI4o", clientKey: "J7v458RE9yIgmvQk5UH3IRMLsozEnoIvjWFj3t6b")

    // Change navigation bar appearance
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(hex: 0x00B7BB)

    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.whiteColor()]

    if let barFont = UIFont(name: "Avenir Next", size: 20.0) {
        UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.whiteColor(), NSFontAttributeName:barFont]
    }

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent

    return true
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
    let installation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
    installation.setDeviceTokenFromData(deviceToken)
    installation.saveInBackground()
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {
    if error.code == 3010 {
        print("Push notifications are not supported in the iOS Simulator.")
    } else {
        print("application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: %@", error)
    }
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    PFPush.handlePush(userInfo)
    if application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.Inactive {
        PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithRemoteNotificationPayload(userInfo)
    }
}

func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}

}
```

+info: when I check the Notification in my device it displays the info from my app and everything is activated.

Comment: So, is `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken ` getting called? Are you ever getting device token?

Comment: Hi @Abhinav, the first time I launch the App it displays the pop-up asking for the permission for sending notifications.

Comment: That is fine but is your above method gets called? Can you please put a log statement in there and print device token.

Comment: Yes, it's called: <28c9b7d9 fcc692ff d6d19ba5 3e8b97b1 68438532 875fbe4e fd53b739 d191bbd3>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trusting you are using push notification enabled profile, I would advise you to check your port number 5223. This is the port on which push notification is delivered. I had similar issue and it turned out that this port was blocked due to firewall restrictions.

If that is not the case for you, I would advise you to go through this troubleshooting [document 1](https://parse.com/questions/not-receiving-push-notifications-on-my-ios-device) and [document 2](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html) step by step.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @Abhinav, some of the documents are in Objective-C, I need more information with Swift 2 because I don't know where to find it. Regards and much appreciated.

Comment: I had to create another provisioning profile and then it work! :)